# Traveling salesman skipping some cities.

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

**There is 10 cities and traveling salesman has to find shortest route to visit just any 5 of them.**

What would be a proper approach to solve 'traveling-salesman-like' problem where there is more cities available than salesman needs to visit?

Comment: That depends... What approach would you use for an ordinary traveling salesman problem?

Comment: I am using existing tools for ordinary traveling salesman problem: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp

So bruteforce method that came to my mind was to just start TSP over and over again on different subset of cities and then select the shortest one. But that is not scalable solution and for a large set it is not feasible at all.

Comment: @JosefP: if you say 5 cities among 10, that doesn't mean "I want a scalable solution" !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With OR-Tools (very good idea) :

1. Allow the solver to drop all nodes with the AddDisjunction() method https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/penalties
2. Add the (custom) constraint $$ \sum_{v \in V} x_v = 5$$
   where $x_v$ takes value $1$ iff node $v$ is visited. You need to use the solver().Add() method :https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/847.